# Symfony Doctrine custom repository method not visible

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a class named ServiceUser which is declared as follows

namespace  AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * ServiceUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="serviceuser")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ServiceUserRepository")
 * 
 */
class ServiceUser
```

I also have a ServiceUserRepository which has inside it a custom repository method named findAllOrderedByName

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
/**
 * ServiceUserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ServiceUserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT s FROM AppBundle:ServiceUser s ORDER BY s.officeName ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

My problem is that this custom method is not accessible in the ServiceUserController.

I'm trying to do this

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $serviceUsers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ServiceUser')->findAllByName();
    return $this->render('serviceuser/index.html.twig', array(
        'serviceUsers' => $serviceUsers,
    ));
}
```

It can see the OOB methods like get findALL() but not my custom method findAllOrderedByName()

Comment: This usually mean that doctrine is not picking up the connection between the entity and the repository.  Try clearing the cache and make sure you don't have any old mapping files lurking under Resources/config/doctrine.

Comment: thanks! Clearing the cache worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to Cerad for pointing me in the direction of clearing the metadata cache.

In case anyone else has the same issue the following command does this

> php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata